# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar imágenes diferentes pero responsivas para todos los dispositivos?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, css3, imagen

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Estoy creado un tipo *slider responsivo* con tres imágenes con diferente tamaño:

- 1.jpg para dispositivos móviles.
- 2.jpg para tablets o mini laptops.
- 3.jpg para pantallas más grandes.

Sin embargo cuando realizo la prueba en móviles, por ende, debería mostrarme la imagen **1.jpg** pero no lo hace, me toma la imagen **3.jpg**.

```css
img{
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6"> </div>
</div>
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://i.ibb.co/RhwrgG9/1.jpg 400w" media="(max-width:500px)">
    <source srcset="https://i.ibb.co/KxGTZYy/2.jpg 800w" media="(max-width:900px)">
      <source srcset="https://i.ibb.co/bXrNhF5/3.jpg" media="(min-width:900px)">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bXrNhF5/3.jpg">
</picture>
```

Comment: Porqué quieres mandar a llamar al servidor tres archivos diferentes que en realidad son la misma imagen? Estás saturando innecesariamente la carga de tu página, y más aún usando Bootstrap, con el cual no necesitas declarar más consultas de medios

Comment: @JheymanMejia Es la misma imagen pero una con diferente resolución y la otra está corrida a la izquierda y se ven más nubes.

Comment: Hola @JheymanMejia. En la práctica las pantallas de los dispositivos no cambian de tamaño de forma dinámica. Por lo que observé en el código del usuario que realiza la pregunta, quiere que se cargue una imagen determinada, en función de la pantalla del dispositivo desde donde se está observando la imagen. Es perfectamente válida la pregunta ya que es una acción necesaria para no saturar un dispositivo de bajo rendimiento con baja resolución de pantalla.

Comment: Por otra parte, el elemento `picture` fue concebido para indicarle al navegador que escoja cargar la imagen en función del dispositivo indicado. [Puede consultar sobre `picture` en la documentación oficial de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture). [También puede consultarlo presionando este enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp). Es decir, no  carga todas las imágenes a la vez. Carga solamente la coincida con el dispositivo indicado o la que tiene por defecto.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Gracias por compartir el enlace.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que en realidad tu código es correcto y que el error viene de la interpretación del inspector de código, que en ocasiones es confuso al ser la misma imagen en diferentes recortes.

Si pruebas tu mismo código con diferentes imágenes podrás comprobar que funciona correctamente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
img{
  max-width: 100%
}

</style>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6"> </div>
    </div>
    
    <picture>
      <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/829/200/200.jpg" media="(max-width:500px)">
      <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/559/200/200.jpg" media="(max-width:900px)">
      <source srcset="https://i.picsum.photos/id/554/200/200.jpg" media="(min-width:900px)">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/64/200/200.jpg">
    </picture>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque no haces de una vez el slider responsive ya que recuerda hay diferentes tamaños de pantalla no importando si es movil, tablet o pc. Sin mencionar que estas usando bootstrap usas su componentes no te compliques.

Si es posible usa este que se adapta a cualquier dispositivo.

```js
       var interleaveOffset = 0.5;

                var swiperOptions = {
                  loop: true,
                  speed: 1000,
                  grabCursor: true,
                  autoplay: true,
                  watchSlidesProgress: true,
                  mousewheelControl: true,
                  keyboardControl: true,
                  navigation: {
                    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
                  },
                  on: {
                    progress: function() {
                      var swiper = this;
                      for (var i = 0; i < swiper.slides.length; i++) {
                        var slideProgress = swiper.slides[i].progress;
                        var innerOffset = swiper.width * interleaveOffset;
                        var innerTranslate = slideProgress * innerOffset;
                        swiper.slides[i].querySelector(".slide-inner").style.transform =
                          "translate3d(" + innerTranslate + "px, 0, 0)";
                      }      
                    },
                    touchStart: function() {
                      var swiper = this;
                      for (var i = 0; i < swiper.slides.length; i++) {
                        swiper.slides[i].style.transition = "";
                      }
                    },
                    setTransition: function(speed) {
                      var swiper = this;
                      for (var i = 0; i < swiper.slides.length; i++) {
                        swiper.slides[i].style.transition = speed + "ms";
                        swiper.slides[i].querySelector(".slide-inner").style.transition =
                          speed + "ms";
                      }
                    }
                  }
                };
                
                var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", swiperOptions);
```

```css
 body {
                background: #eee;
                font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #000;
                background: #404449;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
              }
              
              .swiper-container {
                height: calc(100vh - 120px);
                margin: 60px;
              }
              
              .swiper-slide {
                overflow: hidden;
              }
              
              .slide-inner {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                background-size: cover;
                background-position: center;
              }
              img{
                display:block;
                width:100%;
                height:auto;
              }
              .copy {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 15px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                letter-spacing: 0.06em;
              }
              a {
                color: white;
              }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-inner">
                      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836139/v836139003/63ce1/QThPx7qPzvU.jpg">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-inner" style="background-image:url(https://pp.userapi.com/c412624/v412624691/4136/_da_uAA6ha8.jpg)"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-inner">
                       <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637331/v637331691/48f5f/spHnV42iYVw.jpg">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide-inner">
                      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837139/v837139407/67f52/fFqjq4U2mEk.jpg">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
              </div>             
              
              </body>
</html>
```